# class Book checksum digit function not working

Tags: python

`get_checksum_digit(self)` returns the checksum digit of an isbn. The ISBNs are 13 digits long. The last digit is a checksum digit which is determined from the first 12 digits. The method calculates and returns the checksum digit.

This is my `Book` class:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, bookname, isbn = "N/A", price=0):
        self.bookname, self.isbn, self.price = bookname, isbn, price
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}({}),${:.2f}".format(self.bookname, self.isbn, self.price)
        
    def get_checksum_digit(self):
        even_sum = 0
        odd_sum = 0
        for i in range(len(self.isbn)-1):
            if i%2 == 0:
                even_sum += int(self.isbn[i])
            else:
                odd_sum += int(self.isbn[i])
            i_sum = even_sum + (odd_sum * 3)
            self.checksum = (10 - (i_sum)) % 10
            if self.checksum == 10:
                return 0
        return self.checksum
        
        
    def update_checksum(self):
        self.isbn = self.isbn.replace(self.isbn[-1], str(Book.get_checksum_digit(self)))
        return self.isbn

    def is_valid_isbn(self):
        return int(self.isbn[-1]) == Book.get_checksum_digit(self)
```

My `is_valid_isbn()` method is not working as it should be. Any help please? It isn't showing True after updating the ISBN last number with the checksum.

This is the test case:

```
book1 = Book('Onion Skin','9781603094891',14.99)
print(book1)
print(book1.is_valid_isbn())
book1.update_checksum()
print(book1)
print(book1.is_valid_isbn())
```

This is the output I should get:

```
Onion Skin(9781603094891),$14.99
False
Onion Skin(9781603094894),$14.99
True
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
Onion Skin(9781603094891),$14.99
False
Onion Skin(9784603094894),$14.99
False
```

Comment: What exactly is `get_checksum_digit()` supposed to be doing?  What is `self.checksum`'s relationship to `self.isbn`?

Comment: I have edited my ques, pls check now @Samwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay close attention to the ISBN numbers:

```
Onion Skin(9781603094891),$14.99
              ^        ^
Onion Skin(9784603094894),$14.99
              ^        ^
```

You didn't want to change that first 1 -- changing it invalidates the checksum!  That's happening because of the way you used `replace` in `update_checksum`.

In the process of debugging the code I did some other tidying (I had to simplify `get_checksum_digit` way down just to be able to figure out what it was supposed to be doing).  Here's the final result:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, bookname: str, isbn = "N/A", price=0.0):
        self.bookname, self.isbn, self.price = bookname, isbn, price
        
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.bookname} ({self.isbn}), ${self.price:2f}"
        
    def get_checksum_digit(self) -> str:
        return str((10
            - sum(map(int, self.isbn[0:-1:2]))
            - sum(map(int, self.isbn[1:-1:2])) * 3
        ) % 10)
        
    def update_checksum(self) -> None:
        self.isbn = self.isbn[:-1] + self.get_checksum_digit()

    def is_valid_isbn(self) -> bool:
        return self.isbn[-1] == self.get_checksum_digit()


def test_book_isbn():
    isbn = '9781603094891'
    book = Book('Onion Skin', isbn, 14.99)
    assert not book.is_valid_isbn()
    book.update_checksum()
    assert book.is_valid_isbn()
    assert book.isbn[:-1] == isbn[:-1]
```

Comment: How can I round the checksum to 2 decimal places? The code is kind of confusing

Comment: Why would you need to "round" it?  It's `% 10` so it has to be an `int` from 0 to 9.

Comment: Aah yes sorry I got confused